# When does Twitter api V1.1 will be active?

Tags: api, twitter

When does Twitter api V1.1 will be active?

I can see warnings for Deprecated version, but when do we expect the
new version to come alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this blog post: [2012-09-05](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/current-status-api-v1.1)